# In postgresql, including children relationship in a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I need to create a person table whose columns are id, name, gender, job and children. Then,  children column needs to contain a list of children that person has which are also person objects including name, id, gender, job and children. How such a structure can be stored in a table or more tables? What can be the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2):

> needs to contain a list of children

This is not how it's done in a relational database. Although in theory possible, this would constitute bad design.

In this case you probably want to do it the other way round: store the ID of the *parent* of a person. That way you can easily retrieve all children without the need to de-normalize by storing "a list":

```
create table person
(
  id integer primary key, 
  name   varchar(100) not null, 
  gender varchar(10),
  job    varchar(100),
  parent_id integer references person
);
```

If you want to get a person and all children, use a [recursive common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

```
with recursive person_list as (
  select *
  from person
  where name = 'Arthur' -- the person we want all children for
  union all
  select child.*
  from person child
    join person_list parent on parent.id = child.parent_id
)
select *
from person_list;
```